# Mostrar termos de uma taxonomia aleatoriamente

Tags: wordpress, taxonomia

Eu estou exibindo todas as categorias com suas respectivas imagens, conforme o código abaixo:

```
<?php
categorias = apply_filters('taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array( 'taxonomy' => 'category') );
foreach($categorias as $key => $categoria):             
    if($key < 6):
    ?>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($categoria->term_id);?>">
            <figure>
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($categoria->image_id,''); ?>
            </figure>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/icones/plus.png" class="plus-icone" alt="">    
            <figcaption class="titulo-foto-categoria"><?php echo $categoria->name;?></figcaption>
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php
    endif;
endforeach;?>
```

Foi usado a função `apply_filters` para poder exibir a imagem da categoria, até onde eu consegui achar na internet só dessa forma que é possível fazer isso. Pelo que notei essa função mostra todos os resultados em ordem alfabética e eu preciso mostra-los aleatoriamente ou por data.

É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao que parece `apply_filters` está sempre retornando um array ali, então basta reordenar o array usando [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shuffle.php) pra ficar embaralhado:

```
$categorias = apply_filters('taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array( 'taxonomy' => 'category') );

shuffle( $categorias );

foreach ( $categorias as $key => $categoria ) : //etc
```

Comment: Você fala em reordenar por data, mas não tem uma referência de data no código. Se souber qual o parâmetro que traz essa informação eu posso colocar um exemplo.

Comment: Não tenho como testar agora, mas ficando embaralhado já vai resolver o meu problema. Amanhã cedo irei testar. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Ricardo, deu certinho, agradeço mais uma vez pela ajuda. Nem tinha pensando em pesquisar uma forma de reordenar o array, fiquei focando nas funções do Wordpress.